# flex spark datagrid itemrenderer get owner component

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

in flex3 ,i can get the owner component by listdata in datagrid.but in flex4 ,there is no listdata property in itemrenderer,so what can I do to get the owner datagrid.

I try the `dataGrid= this.automationOwner as DataGrid;`,it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can access listData property in flex 4.
refer [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64fe7-7ff9.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c93)

Comment: in flex4,there is not listdata,I have to use mx lib.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a reference to the DataGrid,then you can try this,
 grid.dataGrid